# How to write this point-free?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Can I write this somehow using ramda?

`const getJobs = data => anotherF('/jobs', data)`

perhaps something like

`const getJobs = anotherF('/jobs', nthArg(0))`

Thank you

Comment: Is your `api.post` asynchronous? [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: nope - all just function calls. I updated the code

Comment: Why "with Ramda?"  What's wrong with your code as written?

Comment: it's about concept not about this particular line of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `anotherF` is already a curried function, then you can just write

```js
const getJobs = anotherF('/jobs')
```

So, if it's not curried, or if you don't know, you can write

```js
const getJobs = curry(anotherF)('/jobs')
```

But there is a good reason to wonder why it would be worth it.  I'm one of the founders of Ramda and I'm a big fan, but I think of it as a toolkit to use when it makes my code easier to read and write.  Any other use seems a misuse.

Answer (score 2):

You can use R.partial to apply `/jobs'` to the function, and return a new function that expects the `data`:

```js
const anotherF = (path, data) => console.log(path, data)

const getJobs = R.partial(anotherF, ['/jobs'])

getJobs('data')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```